# Set input value to 0 when user selects "free shipping" in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

With the following code, users can set up their shipping methods, but I need a solution so that the "price" field changes value to zero when free shipping is selected.

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="disablelist" ng-click="checkitems">Gratis frakt (free shipping)
    <input type="number" ng-disabled="disablelist" class="form-control" value="0" ng-init="price='0'" ng-model="price" name="price">
  </div>
   <div class="well">
     Endelig sluttsum: {{price}}.
     <br>Herav MVA: {{price / 5}}
     <br>Kriterie: 
   </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

First, `ng-click="checkitems"` isn't really doing anything, it should be `ng-click="checkitems()"`, or better yet, `ng-change="checkitems()"`.  And then, in your checkitems method, set the value to 0:

```
$scope.checkitems = function() {
    [...]
    $scope.price = 0; // or something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Create a JS function and make it perform the change to the `price` field once the input is changed for `shipping`